# Error 1004 on Excel.Workbook object set as ThisWorkbook while using Select method

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I can't wrap my head around this issue. I could swear I have done this countless times before but for some reason it keeps erroring out on me.

The problem goes like this:

```
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim curr_wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim StrFile As String

Set curr_wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FromPath & StrFile)

'grabbing some data from one file
wb.Sheets("Customer Information").Range("A2:AA2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

'pasting it on current file
 curr_wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select '<--------error 1004: select method of range failed
'''''''''' The rest of the code not relevant to problem ''''''''''''
```

Now I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is failing. I look into the locals window I can see that curr_wb is indeed set as the workbook the macro is running from. Also "Sheet1" exists in this workbook. The curr_wb and wb variables should be the same type of datatype, how can the select method work on one while not work on the other?

Your help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: You cannot select a range unless its sheet and workbook are active. However you rarely need to select anything anyway.

Comment: wow that was an amazingly fast response. Your suggestion works, which has me confused as I read on another stack overflow message that you do not have to activate a sheet, and that jsut slows down the script. Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce your copying/pasting code to

```
With wb.Sheets("Customer Information")
    .Range("A2:AA2", .Range("A2:AA2").End(xlDown)).Copy curr_wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

As SJR commented this code works if I set curr_wb.Activate right before doing the select.